# 13.04 Eee PC keyboard issue

Tags: keyboard, asus, ubuntu-netbook, 13.04, eeepc

I've just installed **Ubuntu 13.04** on my *ASUS Eee PC 1225B E450* and keyboard is not working although everything was fine in *Ubuntu 12.10*.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Just discovered next problem: touchpad isn't working too. (Usually I'm using USB mouse)

Comment: Now keyboard and touchpad are not working also in 12.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I have fixed this problem.

I added in `/etc/default/grub` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` options `i8042.reset` and `i8042.nomux`, so it looks like this for now:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset i8042.nomux"
```

and updated grub by `sudo update-grub2` command.

Now keyboard and touchpad works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian, did you encountered any problems with keyboard and touchpad while installing Ubuntu 13.04 (not via distro-upgrade, but by bootable USB drive)? I can't handle with that, and you describe only how to fix problem on already installed OS.

Answer (score 0):

@kubuscmg
In order to change boot options of a LiveCD or LiveUSB installer, plese refer to: [Changing the CD's Default Boot Options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD.27s_Default_Boot_Options), chapter "Changing the CD Boot Option Configuration Line" to be exact.